# Problem with error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a error in my code. The code gives

> error 9: subscript out of range.

But I can't find the problem. Who can help me?

`OIWerknemersNummer (I, 1)` is the problem.

```
Dim VeldenperWN As Integer
Dim WNMogelijk As Integer

Sub OrderInvoeren()
    Dim OIWerknemersNummer()
    ReDim OIWerknemersNummer(WNMogelijk, VeldenperWN)

    WNMogelijk = 10
    VeldenperWN = 9    

aantalwerknemers = WBWerknemerslijst.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1


    For I = 1 To WNMogelijk
        OIWerknemersNummer(I, 1) = WBProjectInvoer.Cells(RIJWerknemer - 1 + I, KOLWerknemer) 'error here
        If OIWerknemersNummer(I, 1) > aantalwerknemers Then
            MsgBox "Bij werknemer " & I & " is geen werknemer gekozen. Het project is niet ingevoerd." _
                & " Kies een bestaande werknemer of verwijder het corrosponderende getal in het vakje ernaast.", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next I
```

Thanks for you effort.

Comment: I think you should `ReDim OIWerknemersNummer(WNMogelijk, VeldenperWN)` **after** you initialized your variables `WNMogelijk = 10` and `VeldenperWN = 9` • Also re-think if you really need these 2 variables to be [global](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html). Otherwise declare them within your procedure/sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is out of range because you redim it before you assigne a value to `WNMogelijk` and `VeldenperWN`

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks!!